# Mousewheel scroll down event in C# winform programmatically done

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, eventtrigger

I am trying do image slide show with picturebox Control and a trackbar. The trackbar gets minimum and maximum value corresponds to the number of images to show. I use a timer to get interval period for the slide along with trackbar valuechange.

Now, here is the main thing for each image in the picturebox I'm drawing a rectangle box over the image.

I am not able to draw on the first image when the form get load with first image. But I could do if I scroll the mouse wheel.

I need help to trigger the mouse wheel scroll event once after the first image get loaded.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public event MouseEventHandler MouseWheel;

    //MouseEventArgs k = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Middle,0,0,-1);

    string[] pics = { "C:\\Downloads\\folder_picture_green.png", "C:\\Downloads\\Aetherpal.ico", "C:\\Downloads\\folder_picture_green.png" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
        this.trackBar1.Maximum = (pics.Count() - 1);
        //this.trackBar1.Maximum = 0;

        imageupdate(0);

        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 3000;
        this.MouseWheel += test;
        this.MouseWheel(null, null);
    }

    private void test(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Scrolled");
    }

    private void check(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        //if (Initializing == false) { return; }
        if(this.trackBar1.Value < this.trackBar1.Maximum )
        this.trackBar1.Value += 1;
        else
            timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void Valuechange(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        imageupdate(this.trackBar1.Value);
        if(this.trackBar1.Value < this.trackBar1.Maximum)
            timer1.Start();
    }     

    private void imageupdate(int k)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
        this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pics[k]);
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 5);
        this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
        using (Graphics g = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 10, 10, 100, 50);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yet another CreateGraphics() question.  Minimize and restore the window of your app do see why you should not use it.  Implement the Paint event for pictureBox1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your form to scroll your form (of course with `MouseWheel`):

```
private void Wheel(int ticks, bool down){
  //WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20a
  Message msg = Message.Create(Handle, 0x20a, new IntPtr((down ? -1 : 1)<<16), new IntPtr(MousePosition.X + MousePosition.Y << 16));
  for(int i = 0; i < ticks; i++)
      WndProc(ref msg);
}
//Use it
Wheel(120,true);//Wheel down
Wheel(120,false);//Wheel up
```

**NOTE**: I can see you define a `MouseWheel` event in your own form. This will hide the base `MouseWheel` event, I don't think you have any reason to do this, your own `MouseWheel` **can't** work as the base one, you have to catch the `win32 message` and raise it yourself, we should use the base `MouseWheel` event instead. (Maybe you thought there isn't any `MouseWheel` event in your form class?)